# How to use strcpy and memcpy on int* type

Tags: c, arrays

I want to ***append*** this two array

```
    int array[3]={10,20,5};
    int newArray[3]={1,2,3};
```

into one array like this

```
    array[]={10,20,5,1,2,3};
```

But when I use `strcpy`

```
    strcpy(array,newArray);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(array);i++)
    {
          printf("%d\t",array[i]);
    }
```

The result appear like this

```
   1     20     5     0      0     0
```

When I try to use `memcpy`, it's still the same result.
How can I append two of those array?

Comment: How is `memcpy`,`strcpy` coming into picture when you want to add those two array? Do you mean you want to append them? And looping till `sizeof(array)`???

Comment: Since neither of those arrays are strings, why would you think `strcpy` is relevant? Also -- `sizeof(array)` isn't the same as the number of elements in the array (which you seem to be assuming).

Comment: `int array[3]` cannot hold the 6 elements you require.

Comment: If you ignore the compiler warning about arguments for `strcpy`, if the `int` is litte-endian, then when the `int` pointer `newArray` is treated as `char` pointer, it points to a nul-terminated string with values `1` and `0`, and just look what happened to the original array: the first element was changed from `10` to `1`.

Comment: Your question is lacking a [mcve] for the memcpy case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well **[`strcpy`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.3)** won't work here because you didn't pass null terminated char array to it. It expects `char*`. You can use [**`memcpy`**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.1) to solve the problem. For example:(Illustration)

```
int a[6]={1,2,3};
int b[3]={4,5,6};
memcpy(a+3, b, 3*sizeof(int));
for(size_t  i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++){
    printf("%d\n",a[i] );
}
```

This is copying `3` `int` from array `b` to array `a` starting from index `3`.

Note another thing, you were using `sizeof` wrong way. `sizeof` applied over array returns the size of the whole array - but you don't want that, rather you want number of elements. That you can get by dividing the whole array size with the size of individual element.

In your case, `array` had `3` elements - so you can't copy extra `3` elements to it. To copy elements to it make sure the size of the array is big enough to hold them.

In case of copying it should also be kept in mind that you have to keep track of number of position which are filled correctly and are used already. Otherwise you may lose track of where you should copy elements further.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the question seems to have two variables called `array`, and that it is not clear how much space is allocated for the one used as the target.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler.: I guess the second is shown an example of how it would be after the append is being done...with `3` size array we can't copy `6` elements to it. That's why illustarted and also noted about size in the answer.

Comment: The original posting had `int array[10]={10,20,5};` so it would also need an indication of how many elements were already used.

Comment: @WeatherVane.: Well OP is editing as I am writing answer. It is really problematic.

Comment: @WeatherVane.: Edited to add a note.

Answer (score 0):

First, `strcpy` only works on `char*` and those char arrays need to be null terminated.

Second, you need a way to tell how many elements you have. `sizeof` wont help in your case. Here you have a problem, since you have declared `array` to be of length 10, but you are only using 3 elements; how are you going to keep track of the fact that you are only using part of the array?

To append two arrays you have two choices:

- Do it in-place (i.e. modify one of the arrays). You will need to create it with extra space.
- Create a new array to hold the output. This is the most generic solution.

I'd advise you yo think about how the prototype of a function that performs that operation should be

For example, you can have

```
size_t concatenate(int *a, size_t na, int *b, size_t nb, int **c);
```

Where a, b are your arrays; na, nb their sizes in elements, and c and output argument which will hold the resulting array (which you must `free()` at some point). The return value is the size of the resulting array (na+nb).

An implementation of `concatenate` cuold be

```
size_t concatenate(int *a, size_t na, int *b, size_t nb, int **c)
{
     *c = malloc(sizeof(**c)*(na + nb));
     if (c == NULL)
         return 0;

     memcpy(*c, a, sizeof(**c)*na);
     memcpy(*c + na, b, sizeof(**c)*nb);

     return na+nb;
 }
```